# Angular components/directives

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm used to working with JSF/Primefaces. 
    To use a datepicker, I used to write:

```
    <p:calendar id="button" value="#{calendarView.date3}" showOn="button" />
```

(http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/calendar.xhtml)

Now I'm trying out Angular with angular-ui (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). There is a datepicker directive (http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview).

However, from what I see, if I want to use a field with calendar button and popup, I need to manually create input-group with w field and button and some js functions that would handle the button click.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
          </span>
        </p>
    </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <p class="input-group">
              <input type="date" class="form-control" datepicker-popup ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
              </span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

      $scope.open = function($event) {
          $event.preventDefault();
          $event.stopPropagation();
          $scope.opened = true;
      };
```

I find it hard to believe that everyone writes such components on their own (or uses this amount of code every time they need a date input).
  Are there any predefined directives that would allow me to write one line of code to have a standard datepicker? Where do I find them?

Comment: In Angular, there's a thing called Directives. ng-model is ngModel directive, ng-controller is ngController, etc. You can create your own directive with restricts: attributes, elements, class. Just check the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: That's exactly what I mean. Is seems that trying to use Angular Bootstrap UI I will have to manually write common directives for my project (like a datepicker). Everyone starting a project in Angular would have to do the same (write a directive that will give them a datepicker and other common components). I'm looking for some directive-set to download and use just like in PrimeFaces example...

Comment: I've found 4 components but calendar isn't there. http://subliminalsources.com/81/angularjs-ui-component-directives/ You can follow his steps, make your own directives and share them as a library  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now I can answer my own question - there is no "standard" library that will make the angular html templates code as concise as I would like it to be.

You need to write this much code - but, in return, you have a great freedom in customising the layout.

Bootstrap and material are great - thank you for all the answers!

Answer (score 0):

There are lots out there. You could use [Bootstrap UI](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) or [AngularStrap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/datepickers).

You could also take a look at some of the date pickers on [ngmodules.org](http://ngmodules.org/modules?query=datepicker)

Comment: The example in description is from Bootstrap UI (http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview). It forces me to write inputs, buttons and js functions. I believe there should be a datepicker that's like in the primefaces example - where all you need to specify is the ng-model = "myDate". (Or am I missing something?)

Answer (score 0):

From my research and experience with dates and datetime in HTML5 and Angular; the best practice right now for Datetime is to make good use of HTML5 and moment.js. You can bind directly to input directives ng-model. If you just need a date picker, then make use of the angular-ui-datepicker directives. Also Angular Material is awesome. Check it out [here](http://logbon72.github.io/angular-material-datetimepicker/)

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
        <label for="fltrStartDate"> Start Date: </label>
        <input id="fltrStartDate" type="datetime-local" ng-model="$ctrl.startDate">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label for="fltrEndDate"> Ends Date: </label>
        <input id="fltrEndDate" type="datetime-local" ng-model="$ctrl.endDate">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use latest angular material directives as very simple tags

```
<md-datepicker ng-model="myDate"><md-datepicker>
```

All demos available [here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/datepicker)